# Pull from two dictionaires based on keys, sometimes key isn't in one dictionary in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am new to python and I am using python 2.7. I have two dictionaries that have the same keys. One dictionary is always the same. The other may not have all the matching keys that are in the first dictionary. I have tried many variations based on other questions in Stack overflow on this topic.

I have even tried testing with the following code. The part that doesn't work is comparing the keys in the different dictionaries.
Sample Dict:

```
clubDict = {'001':'Alabama','066':'MountainWest','602':'The Auto Club Group'}

data = {'001':6021, ,'066':1134}
```

As you can see there is no key 602 in the data dictionary. The data dict is being built in this code from a csv file that gets multiple numbers added for a total. Much of this code was answered in stack overflow.

the code worked when I didn't have the if, elifs in it. However the print statement would give differetn results when printed. this is do to missing keys in data{}. I added an if, else to try to compare the keys using pass. Still wouldn't compare. so i have tried what you see now.

here is part of my code:

```
def getTotals():

    result = defaultdict(int)
    regexp = re.compile(r'(?:ttp_ws_sm|ttpv1)_(\d+)_')

    with open(os.path.join(source, 'ttp_13_08.csv'), 'r') as f:
        rows = csv.reader(f)

        #adds total values for each club code (from csv file)
        for row in rows:
            match = regexp.search(row[1])
            if match:
                result[match.group(1)] += int(row[13])
        for key, value in result.items():
            data.update(result.items())

        for value, key in clubDict.items():
            #f = open(output_path + filename, 'a')
            shared_keys = set(clubDict.keys()).union(data.keys())

            if key not in data:
                print "No counts avialable"
            elif key not in clubDict:
                print "Check for Club code"
            elif data[key] == clubDict[key]:
                print 'match'#, '{0}, {1}, {2}'.format(key, value, data[value])
            else:
                print '{0}, {1}, {2}'.format(key, value, data[value])
    file.close

def main():

try:
    getTotals()
except:
    print "No more results"
```

the results aren't what i need.

this is the desired results:

```
Alabama 001 6021

MountainWest 066 1134.
```

I have reviewed many q/a in stack overflow and cannot seem to get these results. I could be just searching incorrectly on my question.

Comment: You are looping over `result.items()` then calling `.update()` with `result.items()` *each time*, ignoring both `key` and `value`. The whole loop can be replaced by one `data.update(result)` call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You swapped the `value` and `key` in your loop:

```
for value, key in clubDict.items():
```

`.items()` gives you `(key, value)` tuples.

Reworking your code a little to remove redundacies:

```
def getTotals():
    result = defaultdict(int)
    regexp = re.compile(r'(?:ttp_ws_sm|ttpv1)_(\d+)_')

    with open(os.path.join(source, 'ttp_13_08.csv'), 'r') as f:
        rows = csv.reader(f)

        #adds total values for each club code (from csv file)
        for row in rows:
            match = regexp.search(row[1])
            if match:
                result[match.group(1)] += int(row[13])
        data.update(result)

        for key in clubDict.viewkeys() & data:
            club_value, data_value = clubDict[key], data[key]
            if club_value == data_value:
                print 'match'
            else:
                print '{0}, {1}, {2}'.format(key, club_value, data_value)
```

You already calculated the intersection of the two dictionaries, which gives you keys only present in both, but you do need to loop over that intersection itself, not `clubDict`.

I used [`dict.viewkeys()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys) to get a set-like object directly, which can be intersected with another iterable, like the `data` dictionary, very efficiently, without intermediary results.

Comment: Brilliant. That worked perfect. I spent a lot of time on this.